# Ember Integration: Trigger click event on root element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I'm writing some ember integration tests, and I'm running into some problems with testing everything on my component. For instance, I have a component that looks like

```
// my-component.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  click() {
    console.log('here');
  }
});
```

And the test that looks like this

```
// my-component-test.js
describeComponent(
  'my-component',
  'Integration: MyComponentComponent',
  {
    integration: true
  },
  function() {
    describe('interacting', function() {
      beforeEach(function() {
        this.render(hbs`
          {{my-component}}
        `);
      });

      it('registers the click', function() {
        this.$().click();
      });
    });
  }
);
```

In the actual case I obviously want to test what the component is doing on that click, but unfortunately this trigger doesn't work (Not getting the log). Anyone have an answer as to how to trigger the click event on the root element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an Ember component integration test, `this.$()` does not select the component's element. It selects the parent element into which the component is rendered.

So if you render a component with

`` this.render(hbs`{{my-component id="my-component}}`); ``

then you can click on the component's element with

`this.$('#my-component').click();`